# Tags on different Stack Exchange sites overlap

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange

I have posted a question with [fftw](/questions/tagged/fftw) tag on Stack Overflow. It turns out there are are loads of useful Q&A fft(w) there.  But, then I scroll through the stack exchange menu in the upper right corner and find out that there is a "Computational Science" stack exchange category which is in spirit closer to most of what is discussed under fftw on StackOverflow. When I searched for fftw tag on Comp. Sci. stack exchange, I also got few additional Q&A-s, but not including any from SO.

I see at least two issues with this.

1. When asking a question at either of the mentioned Exchange websites, are both of them checked for similar material? I mean the list that pops up while typing in the title of the question.
2. In both cases, perhaps for the historical reasons, the same tag is used for almost the same topics. Shouldn't votes obtained at one of the sites carry over to the other automatically in this specific case?

I have the feeling the tag-category connection should be more fluid. The tags themselves should sometimes be a stronger selection criteria than the particular Exchange site one is logged in at.

Comment: Related maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147096/span-stack-exchange-sites-for-tags-searches-and-related-questions

Answer (score 3):

> When asking a question at either of the mentioned Exchange websites, are both of them checked for similar material?

No, only the site you're currently asking on is searched for similar questions.

> Shouldn't votes obtained at one of the sites carry over to the other automatically in this specific case?

No, I don't think so, for a couple of reasons.

1. Tags often overlap, but your contribution to a site is specific to that site.
2. There are cases where tag names mean different things on different sites. Sometimes the difference will be obvious (for example, an acronym might mean something completely different on a programming site than it does on the physics site), or it could be subtle (you'd answer different kinds of Excel questions on Stack Overflow than you would on Super User).

To deal with your specific problem, I'd suggest searching with Google to find out if your question has been asked *anywhere* before posting on a Stack Exchange site. If you can't find an answer, then search on individual sites to find out which site best caters to the specific kind of question you're asking.

Comment: I have found a similar question on SO meta. Just for the reference: [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261914/whats-the-purpose-of-splitting-stack-exchange-into-many-sub-sites) .